# Add data points to BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: plotting, data, charts

I am working with `BoxWhiskerChart` to plot my data, but I can't figure out how to add the data points to the plot. I have read the help function many times and looked around this site, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Basically what I want to do is to have a graph like I obtained with Origin (see pic).

[image: Box and Whisker plot obtained with Origin]

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please edit this question to show your data and the code you used to make your plot. People will need that to work on your problem. The answer probably will involve the plot option `Epilog`.

Comment: You can add a point or any other graphics to a `BoxWhiskerChart` using `Epilog`:  `SeedRandom[42];
data = Table[
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], 1], 
   100], {\[Mu], {0, 3, 2, 5}}]; BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{3, 6}]}]`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the option [`ChartElementFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html). Obviously, you will need to add more to this, but here is the data portion:

```
Clear[dataWhisker];
dataWhisker[{{xmin_, xmax_}, _}, data_, _] := 
 With[{x = (xmax + xmin)/2}, {Opacity[0.2], Point[{x, #} & /@ data]}]

BoxWhiskerChart[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {5, 100}], 
  ChartElementFunction -> dataWhisker]
```

[image]

There are a couple of additions that are possible like setting the maker, etc., and if I get the time, I will add to this. In the meantime, this should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[cF]
cF[cedf_: "BoxWhisker", o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Dynamic@With[{col = Darker@Darker@CurrentValue["Color"]}, {EdgeForm[{col, Thick}], 
    ChartElementDataFunction[cedf, o][##], 
    ListPlot[Thread[{Mean[#[[1]]], #2}], PlotStyle -> col, PlotMarkers -> #3[[1]]][[1]]}] &
```

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[3]
dt = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {5, 10}];
markers = Graphics`PlotMarkers[][[;; 5]];

BoxWhiskerChart[Thread[dt -> markers], {{"MeanMarker", 1}, {"MedianMarker", None}}, 
 ChartStyle -> 1, ChartElementFunction -> cF[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
BoxWhiskerChart[Thread[dt -> markers], {{"MeanMarker", 1}, {"MedianMarker", None}}, 
 ChartStyle -> 1, ChartBaseStyle -> FaceForm[], 
 ChartElementFunction -> cF[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]